# I get a PHP unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Tags: php

It's a part of PHP automatic generated feed i only know bits and peaces of PHP so please stay calm with me but I'm getting:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in
>   /home/u664558657/public_html/feed/example_rss2.php on line 68

```
   switch($monitor->$newItem=>addElementArray(array('title'=>getStatus())
    {
        case STATUS_ONLINE :
            p('<h2 class="online">Online</h2>');
            break;
        case STATUS_OFFLINE :
            p('<h2 class="offline">Offline</h2>');
            break;
        case STATUS_PAUSED :
            p('<h2 class="waiting">Paused</h2>');
            break;
        case STATUS_DOWNTIME :
            p('<h2 class="waiting">Scheduled Downtime</h2>');
            break;
        case STATUS_UNPOLLED :
            p('<h2 class="waiting">Unpolled</h2>');
            break;
    }', 'link'=>'http://feed.vipo.ca/', 'description'=>'test description'));

    $TestFeed->addItem($newItem);
```

Comment: $monitor->$newItem->addElementArray(), not $monitor->$newItem=>addElementArray()

Comment: The last line doesn't look kosher either

Answer (score 4):

```
switch($monitor->$newItem=>addElementArray(array('title'=>getStatus())
```

Should be:

```
switch($monitor->$newItem->addElementArray(array('title'=>getStatus())
```

Have a look at `=>` and change it to `->`

Answer (score 3):

`T_DOUBLE_ARROW` is the token for `=>`. So the error is for `$newItem=>addElementArray`. It should be

```
$newItem->addElementArray
```

also there should be two more parenthesises after  `array('title'=>getStatus())`. Like

```
array('title'=>getStatus())))
```

Even After that this part **makes no sense**

```
', 'link'=>'http://feed.vipo.ca/', 'description'=>'test description'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
switch($monitor->$newItem->addElementArray(array('title'=>getStatus())))
{
    case STATUS_ONLINE :
        p('<h2 class="online">Online</h2>');
        break;
    case STATUS_OFFLINE :
        p('<h2 class="offline">Offline</h2>');
        break;
    case STATUS_PAUSED :
        p('<h2 class="waiting">Paused</h2>');
        break;
    case STATUS_DOWNTIME :
        p('<h2 class="waiting">Scheduled Downtime</h2>');
        break;
    case STATUS_UNPOLLED :
        p('<h2 class="waiting">Unpolled</h2>');
        break;
}
```

Comment: thenk you everyone but now it has a problem on line 2 with {

Comment: here is a direct link for you to reed the code [link](http://vipo.ca/feed/source.txt)

Comment: @DavidDumouchel : check my edited code and try again